# How to use a clear button to clear notification screen in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, notifications

How to clear pop scroll bar notification using single clear button in laravel 5.5
Notification using jquery and ajax  database
I have crm project so i got notification like
Advance slaray request approved
Live request approved.
I want a clear button to clear notifiaction bar

Answer (score 0):

Laravel gives you mark read/delete for notification so you can have a button wherever you want to read/remove all notifications and on ajax you can mark or remove the notification

From laravel docs

```
  $user = App\Models\User::find(1);

  foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification) {
        $notification->markAsRead();
   }
```

However, instead of looping through each notification, you may use the markAsRead method directly on a collection of notifications:

```
$user->unreadNotifications->markAsRead();
```

You may also use a mass-update query to mark all of the notifications as read without retrieving them from the database:

```
// For specific user
$user = App\Models\User::find(1); 

$user->unreadNotifications()->update(['read_at' => now()]);
```

You may delete the notifications to remove them from the table entirely:

```
// Or can delete 
$user->notifications()->delete();
```